# React useEffect with async functions and Intersection Observer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am struggling to find a pattern that works for an infinite scroll component I am working on for reference I am using the `react-intersection-observer` hook. The problem is that my `fetchData` function is being called twice when the `inView` state is true. I have tried quite a few solutions and none of them seem to work. The flow seems to be:

1. Page loads `inView` is false.
2. User scrolls `inView` becomes true.
3. `fetchData` is asynchronously called and useEffect ends.
4. `res` is finally returned and `setQueryData` finally updates the state.
5. This triggers the `useEffect` to execute again but since the data has just been set, it hasn't been rendered yet and pushed the `inView` linked component down out of the way.
6. Since `inView` is still `true` another `fetchData` is executed.

It seems like I need to make `inView` false immediately after the `useEffect` is run but not sure if this possible or correct, any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
type LoadMoreState = {
  data: QueryDatabaseResponse[];
  nextCursor: string | undefined;
};

export function LoadMore({ cursor }: { cursor: string }) {
  const { ref, inView } = useInView();
  const [queryData, setQueryData] = useState<LoadMoreState>({
    data: [],
    nextCursor: cursor,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      if (inView) {
        try {
          const res = await getGoodFirstIssues({
            page_size: 10,
            start_cursor: queryData.nextCursor,
          });
          setQueryData((prevData) => ({
            data: prevData.data.concat(res),
            nextCursor: res.next_cursor || undefined,
          }));
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("There was an error fetching the data", error);
        }
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [inView, queryData]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you need `queryData` inside the `useEffect`, because of the `nextCursor`, but it also triggers the `useEffect`, while `inView` is still `true`.

Store the `next_cursor` in a ref (`nextCursorRef`), and remove it from the dependencies of the `useEffect`:

```
export function LoadMore({ cursor }: { cursor: string }) {
  const nextCursorRef = useRef<string | undefined>();
  const { ref, inView } = useInView();
  const [queryData, setQueryData] = useState<QueryDatabaseResponse[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      if (inView) {
        try {
          const res = await getGoodFirstIssues({
            page_size: 10,
            start_cursor: nextCursorRef.current,
          });
          
          nextCursorRef.current = res.next_cursor || undefined;
          setQueryData((prevData) => prevData.concat(res));
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("There was an error fetching the data", error);
        }
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [inView]);
```

I would also refactor this a bit more, to prevent defining and calling `fetchData` if `inView` is `false`:

```
export function LoadMore({ cursor }: { cursor: string }) {
  const nextCursorRef = useRef<string | undefined>();
  const { ref, inView } = useInView();
  const [queryData, setQueryData] = useState<QueryDatabaseResponse[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!inView) return undefined; // if not in view no need to define and call fetchData

    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await getGoodFirstIssues({
          page_size: 10,
          start_cursor: nextCursorRef.current,
        });

        nextCursorRef.current = res.next_cursor || undefined;
        setQueryData((prevData) => prevData.concat(res));
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("There was an error fetching the data", error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [inView]);
```